# Run a SQL Server Agent Job from Python

Tags: python, sql, restore, database-backups, sql-server-agent

I am trying to trigger a SQL Server Agent Job (takes a backup of the db and places into a directory) from python.  Unfortunately, I haven't found anything in regards to python triggering a SQL Server Agent Job (only the other way around, SQL Server Agent Job triggering a python script).

Once I get that backup, I want to restore this db into a different SQL Server using the same python script.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can run a job from Transact-SQL from Python:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'My Job Name';  
GO
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.

Comment: I am having trouble with this because when I do that, I don't know what dbo to point it too.  The SQL Server Agent Job is not in the 'Databases' folder but outside of it.  So when I run this code, it says, 'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_start_job'.'  Does that make sense?  And I when I try to say 'Use servername' it says that the server name isn't a Db.  I'm not sure I'm understanding but it feels like in my case, the SQL Server Agent doesn't live in a Db, but that's where everyone elses does (almost like a SP)

Comment: First you need a valid connection string to connect to the database. That includes server, port, username and password (unless you have configured a different authentication). From there on, you need permissions to execute this SP (you can read more about that on that documentation page under "Permissions").

Comment: @ElliotGitter Try `USE msdb` first, or `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job ...`. Because SQL Server Agent uses the `msdb` system database